# mysql join 2 tables in same column

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've create **PHP** website that have 2 tables in one database, **2 to type of users first is editor user (c) and normal user  (b)**

the first table **(irp_members)**

**username - email - phone - usertype - parea**

the second table **(irp_mem_papers)**

**username - email - phone - pcountry - fname - pauthor - parea**

i try to do **mysql join** if user is logged in and his type is **editor (c)** then create mysql join get any record from second table **(irp_mem_papers)** where **parea field** from first table **(irp_members)** is same  **parea field** in second table **(irp_mem_papers)**

mysql code is

```
SELECT irp_members.parea, irp_mem_papers.pauthor,irp_mem_papers.phone, irp_members.username
FROM irp_mem_papers 
WHERE irp_members.username = $_SESSION[username]
INNER JOIN irp_mem_papers 
ON irp_members.parea=irp_mem_papers.parea
```

what i mean was if the field in **irp_members.parea** and **irp_mem_papers.parea** are equal in value (for example they both need to be **biology**

Comment: its dosnt work , any idea ?

Comment: Why do you need two table? Use one and create an extra column is_editor and set to true or false

Comment: Agree with Grasper. Its' not a good idea to duplicate data in both table. Or you must have only one table, or you need to have a unique ID in the first and use it as link in the second. But having username - email - phone is not a good idea.

Comment: thats so right , but i need just this like that , thanks for tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure, if the semantics of the query was correct, but the syntax must be like this (WHERE clause goes after JOIN and ON):

```
SELECT irp_members.parea, irp_mem_papers.pauthor,irp_mem_papers.phone, 
irp_members.username
FROM irp_members 
INNER JOIN irp_mem_papers 
ON irp_members.parea=irp_mem_papers.parea
WHERE irp_members.username = $_SESSION[username]
```

Comment: what i mean was if the field in **irp_members.parea** and **irp_mem_papers.parea** are equal in value (for example they both need to be **biology**

Comment: Just noticed, that you joined a table "irp_mem_papers" with itself. What you should do is joining "irp_members" with "irp_mem_papers". I have updated a query in my answer, try it.